# Can I use "scheme" when referring to electronic drawings?

Tags: word-choice

When talking about electronic drawings is it correct to use scheme or should I only use schematic?

Comment: I would use schematic. Schema to me is a database overview or XML description - scheme is something else

Comment: @mplungjan Do you mean schema (when talking about DB)?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. And [Scheme](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+scheme) does not sound right either

Comment: In general, "scheme" means "plan", but not "plan" in the sense of a "blueprint."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Schema**

- entity relationship diagrams (ERD) used to visually represent a database or data warehouse
- XML or similar non-physical descriptions

**Schematic**

- physical electronic circuitry diagrams
- diagram of a physical assembly, with a variety of formats e.g. exploded

**Blueprint**

- layout for a physical structure

**Scheme**

- British English: An investment plan or public policy action. There is no pejorative connotation.
- American English: A clever plan of action, possibly unethical or even illegal. There is a definite pejorative connotation.

For electronic drawings, *schematic* is the proper word choice. Do not use *schema*. Do not use *scheme*, especially not if intended for American English.